412 error trying to delete image by digest from DigitalOcean Registry
I wrote a script to delete old images from DigitalOcean Container Registry. It should delete all untagged images and all tagged except last 5 images. But I faced a problem, it deletes 30-40 images and then failed with an error:
Deleting untagged image: sha256:69a840d47d89e193b8bf582660d7ac6b2fd6a14fcc13a9a2c367ffd090c4c5ab
An error occurred: 412 Client Error: Precondition Failed for url: https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry/---/repositories/app/digests/sha256:69a840d47d89e193b8bf582660d7ac6b2fd6a14fcc13a9a2c367ffd090c4c5ab

Does it some kind of rate limit? Or some issue in my code?
Script:
import os
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load DigitalOcean token from .env file
load_dotenv()
DO_TOKEN = os.getenv("DO_TOKEN")
REGISTRY_NAME = "---"
BASE_URL = f"https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/registry/{REGISTRY_NAME}"

HEADERS = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {DO_TOKEN}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

def get_repositories():
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/repositories"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return [repo["name"] for repo in response.json()["repositories"]]

def get_image_digests(repository):
    page = 1
    per_page = 200
    all_tags = []
    all_untagged = []

    while True:
        url = f"{BASE_URL}/repositories/{repository}/digests?page={page}&per_page={per_page}"
        response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        manifests = data.get("manifests", [])

        print(f"Fetched {len(manifests)} tags from repository {repository}, page {page}")

        for manifest in manifests:
            tag_name = manifest.get("tags")
            print(tag_name)
            if not tag_name:
                all_untagged.append(manifest["digest"])
            else:
                all_tags.append(manifest)

        if len(manifests) < per_page:
            break

        page += 1

    print(f"Found {len(all_untagged)} untagged images and {len(all_tags)} tagged images in repository {repository}")

    sorted_tags = sorted(all_tags, key=lambda tag: tag.get("created_at", ""))

    return [tag["digest"] for tag in sorted_tags], all_untagged

def delete_image(repository, digest):
    url = f"{BASE_URL}/repositories/{repository}/digests/{digest}"
    response = requests.delete(url, headers=HEADERS)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(f"Deleted image with digest {digest} from repository {repository}")

def clean_up_repository(repository):
    print(f"Processing repository: {repository}")
    tagged_digests, untagged_digests = get_image_digests(repository)


    for digest in untagged_digests:
        print("Deleting untagged image: " + digest)
        delete_image(repository, digest)

    if len(tagged_digests) <= 5:
        print(f"Repository {repository} has 5 or fewer tagged images. Skipping tagged images cleanup.")
        return

    images_to_delete = tagged_digests[:-5]
    for digest in images_to_delete:
        delete_image(repository, digest)

def main():
    try:
        repositories = get_repositories()
        for repository in repositories:
            clean_up_repository(repository)
        print("Cleanup completed successfully.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Thanks in advance!
